# Empty a Python deque every 10 seconds

Tags: python

I have a Python deque that I append each time in that deque.

```
pre_label = collections.deque(maxlen=5)
while True:
      #do something
      function(name)
      pre_label.append()
```

i have :

```
pre_label = deque(['john', 'zari', 'fai'], maxlen=3)
```

I want to have the following output every 10 seconds :

```
pre_label = deque([], maxlen=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of ways to do this off the top of my head:

1. Threaded solution
   If you're using python 2, or you don't want to do async, this should work:
   Quick disclaimer: I don't use threads all that often, so you should look for more advice on that. :)

```py
from collections import deque

deck = deque([], maxlen=3)

## Threaded solution
from threading import Thread
import time

def clear_deque():
    """ This is a small function to clear the queue and print the contents when cleared"""
    global deck  # You should probably avoid globals, but we need a reference to the underlying object to make the clear actually work. 
    while(True):
        time.sleep(3)  # you'd want to increase this to 10. Also, sleeping at the start to allow some time before the clear to happen the first time.
        contents = list(deck)
        deck = deque([], maxlen=3)
        print("\n |> Deck = {}".format(contents))

t = Thread(target=clear_deque)  # Making a new thread to call this one function
t.daemon=True  # Marking the thread as a daemon, so that it can be killed when the program exits normally
t.start()  # annnd starting the thread!

# And a dumb loop to verify the functionality
while True:
    v = input("Add stuff> ")
    deck.append(v)

t.join()
```

2. If you're using python 3, you can implement a similar solution using an async worker. This example demonstrates how to do it, but if you go the async route, you need to make sure all of your long running processes are async, so it may require a significant re-architecture.

```py
import asyncio
import random
from collections import deque

deck = deque([], maxlen=10)

async def clear_deque():
    global deck
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        contents = list(deck)
        print(f"\n |> Deck contents: {contents}")
        deck = deque([], maxlen=10)


async def add_to_deque():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        v = random.randint(1, 10)
        print(f"Adding: {v}")
        deck.append(v)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
actions = asyncio.gather(add_to_deque(), clear_deque())
loop.run_until_complete( actions )
```